# Количество строк во всех текстовых файлах включая pdf, doc

Tags: java, строки, файлы

Вопрос (Java) или очень простой, или очень сложный (по своему опыту определить не могу)

Нужно посчитать количество строк в файле (любого текстового формата). Если с java и txt еще поможет:

```
private static void getStringCount(File file)
    {
        int i=0;
        String line=null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try{
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while(bufferedReader.readLine()!=null)
                i++;
            System.out.println("СТРОК - " + i);
            bufferedReader.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
```

то на pdf, doc и т.д., цифры идут уже совсем не те.

Кто-нибудь знает, как это можно реализовать? Неужели на каждый формат нужно писать обработчик и подключать библиотеку?

Comment: pdf и doc - не текстовые форматы, а бинарные. Соответственно нужно знать структуру файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю всё-таки придётся на каждый тип писать что-то своё. Форматы очень разнятся, как я понимаю. Хотя, может глупость скажу, можно попробовать искать символы конца строки в файлах в байтовом виде, но тут может быть много ложных срабатываний, как, например, в FB2, так что всё-таки не вариант

Comment: я подозреваю, что вначале для разных типов файлов ещё придется дать определение, что такое "количество строк". К примеру, для того же pdf не все так однозначно (пример - в pdf две страницы с картинками, на которых по одному квадрату. Сколько там строк?)